# How to prevent third party apps from detecting user idleness?

Tags: c#, winforms

In *Discord* there is **no** option to *disable* idle detection, so i want to write a little app which simulates user so that discord and other apps **don't think I'm idle.**

I've tried using Cursor. Position and that teleports the mouse around on the screen but it does not prevent idle detection.

How can i simulate user input in c# windows forms application so as to fool idle detection in discord and other apps?

Comment: I don't know if _Windows Journal Record/Playback hooks_ constitutes but it might be worth looking into

Comment: @MickyD i dont know why that happened i added "idle" as a tag and it came out the other side as python-idle. I've removed it, thanks for spotting.

Comment: Not a problem good sir

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the following line of code. This just sends alt+tab to windows. Works for my purposes though a less disruptive approach would be preferable, like maybe a windows click or something.

```
SendKeys.SendWait("%({tab})");
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below in the button Click event could be placed into Timer.Tick event which toggles <kbd>scroll lock</kbd> button.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflow_PressScrollLock
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void keybd_event(
            byte bVk, 
            byte bScan, 
            uint dwFlags, 
            UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private static void PressScrollLock()
        {
            const byte vkScroll = 0x91;
            const byte keyeventfKeyup = 0x2;

            keybd_event(vkScroll, 0x45, 0, (UIntPtr)0);
            keybd_event(vkScroll, 0x45, keyeventfKeyup, (UIntPtr)0);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This would go in a Timer.Tick event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void ExecuteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PressScrollLock();
            PressScrollLock();
        }
    }
}
```